# Return string with character - where the numbers follow each other

Tags: python

I decided to write a function that sorts the list of numbers and produces a string in which the numbers that go one after another are replaced by a symbol `-`.

For example -> `[6,7,8,99,100,2,3,4,1]`
And function need return -> `'1,2-4,6-8,99-100'`

or

For example -> `[12,7,8,9,9,9,7,8,1,2,3,5,100]`
And function need return -> `'1-3,5,7-9,12,100'`

or

```
range(100) # return '0-100'
```

I started with this

```
def func(list):
   sort_list = sorted(list) 
   print(sort_list) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 99, 100]

func([6,7,8,99,100,2,3,4,1])
```

How can I return a string with `-` where elements go one after another.
I think here I need to somehow apply the method `'-'.join`. Maybe?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why doesn't it start with '1-4,6-8,...' rather than '1,2-4,...'?

Comment: @DarrylG, because after the number 1 does not go 2 -> `2,3,4,1` -> 1,2-4

Comment: interesting question, so you're looking for **intervals**...what are the rules behind how the intervals are formed ? from what I can see, the odd numbers are skipped ? **2 - 4** (3 is dropped), **6 - 8** (7 is dropped), I'm not sure if this is a pattern... how do you decide where the `-` goes ?

Comment: @Marius Mucenicu, the numbers that go one after another are replaced by `-` -> `[8,9,10,2,3,4,12,13]` -> `'2-4,8-10,12-13'`

Comment: Does the order in the initial list matter? If the list was, say, `5, 4, 3, 2, 1` is `1-5` the expected output? Are numbers guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Still, I don't understand '1-4,6-8,...' vs. '1,2-4,...' since you imply we are looking at the numbers after they have been sorted.  In sorted order 1 is part of the sequence 1-4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom `find_ranges` function:

```
def find_ranges(lst):
    res = [[lst[0]]]   # initialize with 1st number

    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        diff = lst[i] - res[-1][-1]    # compare current and previous numbers
        if diff > 1 or diff < 0:
            res.append([])
        elif diff == 0:
            continue
        res[-1].append(lst[i])
    return ','.join(f'{r[0]}-{r[-1]}' if len(r) > 1 else str(r[0]) 
                    for r in sorted(res))


print(find_ranges([6, 7, 8, 99, 100, 2, 3, 4, 1]))
# 1,2-4,6-8,99-100
print(find_ranges([12, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 5, 100]))
# 1-3,5,7-8,7-9,12,100
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to group the elements depending on whether they are exactly `1` larger than the last element. You can do this in a simple loop, either keeping track of the last element in a separate variable, or using `[-1]` to access the last element of the last group thus identified.

```
lst = [6,7,8,99,100,2,3,4,1]

grps = [[lst[0]]] # start with group with first element
for x in lst[1:]:
    if x == grps[-1][-1] + 1:
        grps[-1].append(x) # add to last group
    else:
        grps.append([x])   # start new group
# [[6, 7, 8], [99, 100], [2, 3, 4], [1]]
```

Then, you can sort those groups (the default sort will sort them by the first element in the group, which is sufficient) and create the string representations from those:

```
res = [str(g[0]) if len(g) == 1 else f"{g[0]}-{g[-1]}" for g in sorted(grps)]
# ['1', '2-4', '6-8', '99-100']
```